# How to set sub table name while using tdengine's schemaless insert

Tags: tdengine

I know that tdengine support schemaless insert. And there are three line protocols that tdengine supports. The follow is the sample code from [taosdata's website](https://www.taosdata.com/cn/documentation/connector#c-cpp) schemaless chapeter.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <taos.h>
int main() {
  const char* host = "127.0.0.1";
  const char* user = "root";
  const char* passwd = "taosdata";
  // connect to server
  TAOS* taos = taos_connect(host, user, passwd, "test", 0);
  // prepare the line string
  char* lines1[] = {
      "stg,t1=3i64,t2=4f64,t3=\"t3\" c1=3i64,c3=L\"passit\",c2=false,c4=4f64 1626006833639000000",
      "stg,t1=4i64,t3=\"t4\",t2=5f64,t4=5f64 c1=3i64,c3=L\"passitagin\",c2=true,c4=5f64,c5=5f64 1626006833641000000"
  };
  // schema-less insert
  TAOS_RES* res = taos_schemaless_insert(taos, lines1, 2, TSDB_SML_LINE_PROTOCOL, TSDB_SML_TIMESTAMP_NANO_SECONDS);
  if (taos_errno(res) != 0) {
    printf("failed to insert schema-less data, reason: %s\n", taos_errstr(res));
  }
  taos_free_result(res);
  // close the connection
  taos_close(taos);
  return (code);
}
```

I know this will create the stable  "stg" and create substable for the incoming data record. I want to ask can I control the subtable's name and how to configure the name?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot configure subtable name in TDengine database
Please refer this link for how subtable name is generated: https://docs.tdengine.com/reference/schemaless/#main-processing-logic-for-schemaless-writing